# C# adding to textbox, column values in one or more rows that I have selected

Tags: c#, sql, listview, textbox, addition

My project has 5 records in listview. When I click these records, I want them added to the text box. but when I select a single line and add, all 5 records are added to the text box. When I select 5 lines, it prints 5 times 5 values.When I select and insert one or more lines, I want to add the values of those lines to the text box. I'll share the code.

```
private void mailTopla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].Checked)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("select email from musteriKayit",sqlConnection);
            komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();

            while (oku.Read())
            {
                if (listView1.Items[i].Checked)
                {
                        if (kimeTextBox.Text == "")
                        {
                            kimeTextBox.Text += (oku["email"].ToString().Trim());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            kimeTextBox.Text += "," + (oku["email"].ToString().Trim());
                        }
                }
            }
            oku.Close();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your second if condition.  One you have found a "checked" item this will always be true.  So your while loop will add all five items that it reads.  If you check all five items, it loops through all the data 5 times and you get 25 items.  The second if needs to match between the value of the item that is checked and the value of the data being read.  Only when there is a match should you add the data to the control.